# Typescript type requiring any one attribute of an object to be defined: how?

Tags: typescript, types, static-analysis, typechecking

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
interface qux {
    foo?: string;
    bar?: number | string;
}

function foobar(x: qux) { ...; something_frobz(x); ...; }
```

Problem: I can call `foobar("hello, world")`, even though this causes `something_frobz` to misbehave. I would like to catch and reject calls to `foobar` with string argument at compile time, while altering the structure of qux as little as possible. What's the best way of going about this?

My own solution is to make one field required; that field has a sensible default value, and AFAIK string doesn't have any fields with the same name. That's a bit of a hack, but it works.

Another approach might be to have foobar take a union type of `first-field-is-required | second-field-is-required | ... | hundredth-field-is-required`, but then I have to maintain N almost-identical copies of qux (for N > 1) and that never goes well.

Is there anything better?

Comment: Check out this issue: [Support some non-structural (nominal) type matching](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typescript version 2.2 - 2.3**

To prevent passing "primitives" as a parameter, you can require it to be an `object`:

```
function foobar(x: qux & object) { }

foobar(''); //error
foobar(1); //error
foobar({a:1}); //error

foobar({foo:'bar'}); //ok
```

**Typescript version >= 2.4** `object` constraint is not required anymore. See @dbandstra's answer for more information.

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way of defining an interface such that `& object` is part of it? I can do `interface blah { ... }; export type foo = blah & object;` but can I do it in a single type declaration/definition?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that Typescript 2.4 addresses this problem.

> TypeScript 2.4 introduces the concept of “weak types”. A weak type is any type that contains nothing but all-optional properties. [...] In TypeScript 2.4, it’s now an error to assign anything to a weak type when there’s no overlap in properties. That includes primitives like `number`, `string`, and `boolean`.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/#stricter-checks-on-weak-types